# Dailymotion API get refresh token by request.post python

Tags: python, dailymotion-api

I want to get refresh token from Dailymotion API by this code

```
def get_refresh_token(code):
    platform = Platform.objects.get(name='Dailymotion')
    secret_key = platform.secret_key
    api_key = platform.api_key
    redirect_uri = platform.callback_url
    params = {
        'code' : code,
        'client_id' : api_key,
        'client_secret' : secret_key,
        'grant_type':'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri':redirect_uri
    }
    r = requests.post('https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token',data=params)
    print (r.json())
    print(code)
    print(r.data)
    refresh_token = r.json().get('refresh_token')
    return refresh_token
```

but it's not working.  the error is : `{'error_description': 'Invalid authorization code.', 'error': 'invalid_grant'}`
.I tried with the same code,grant_type... post from Chrome extensions and it works. What did i do wrong with python code?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I'd try breaking it down starting with Chrome. Use a header plugin to see the exact back-and-forth that it's doing with the site. Then use curl to recreate it successfully on the command line. Then try it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`def get_refresh_token(self, code):
     args = {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': code,
            'client_id': DAILYMOTION_API_KEY,
            'client_secret': DAILYMOTION_API_SECRET,
         }
         url = 'https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token'
         data = urllib.urlencode(args)
         request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
         response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
           html = response.read()
        obj_Response = literal_eval(html)
            return obj_Response`

while getting AccessToken we get a parameter 'code' here we have to put that value in place of code.